# Preventing tap-and-hold from selecting nearby text

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch, touch-event

If a user taps and holds their finger on both iOS and Android, the native browser behavior is to highlight the nearest selectable text.

I'm building a webapp where there is a chart similar to the chart in the iOS Stocks app, where you can tap the chart for details about a specific point, and slide your finger along the chart for details about different points.

The interaction is working fine, but both platforms are still selecting the text beneath the chart when the user taps and holds.

I am starting the interaction using the `touchstart` event, and updating what is displayed on 
 the chart during `touchmove`. Both events call `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`.

Is there something I can do to tell the browser to not select the text underneath the chart?

Note: I do not want to set `user-select: noselect` on the text beneath the chart, as I **do** want the text to be selectable otherwise. Also, these charts can be moved around, and I won't always know what text is beneath them.

If it helps, here's an image of the UI I'm talking about, taken on iOS. This screenshot was taken after I tapped and held the chart. As you can see, it highlighted "Withdrawals". This same behavior occurs on Android.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add `user-select: noselect` on your document when `touchstart` is called and remove it then

Comment: That’s a great suggestion. I’ll give it a shot.

Comment: Update: that works. It feels a little bit hacky since iOS still triggers the haptic feedback on the press, but I'll likely go with this unless a better solution is presented. Thanks @AdrienLeloir!

Comment: Nice ! On IOS you can use -webkit prefix, it's work on my iphone XS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working solution : Add `user-select: noselect` on your document when touchstart is called and remove it then

Prefixes for compatibility with all browsers [user-select compatibility for browsers](https://www.arungudelli.com/tutorial/css/disable-text-selection-in-html-using-user-select-css-property/#disable-text-selection-highlighting-in-ios-safari-using-css)

Comment: Will mark as approved in a couple of days; I want to wait to see if any other ideas come in first.

Comment: Sorry that it took awhile, but I just accepted this as the accepted answer. I've been using this for a couple of weeks now without issue. It's working so well that I completely forgot it was ever a problem! Thanks a ton Adrien!

Comment: In react for example, in the `onTouchStart` handler, run something like: `document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";`.  
And in the `onTouchStop`: `document.body.style.webkitUserSelect = null;`